# Firebase Database update data deletes old children

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to add nested children in my firebase database. 
The structure of my json is

```
{
    "Users": {

    "user1": {
        "courses": {
            "science": {
                "maxMarks": 100,
                "teacher": "Andrew",
                "title": "Amazing Science",
                "status": "cleared"

            },
            "maths": {
                "maxMarks": 100,
                "teacher": "Simon",
                "title": "Elementary Mathematics",
                "status": "cleared"
            },
            "history": {
                "maxMarks": 80,
                "teacher": "Sarah",
                "title": "History",
                "status": "cleared"
            }
        }

    }
}
```

}

As soon as I add a new course, it is overwriting my whole course child instead of adding a new child inside.

I have also tried updateChildren but no success..
Please help.

```
FirebaseDatabase mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");


DatabaseReference newPostRef = mDatabase.child("user1").child("courses").child("Calculus").push();

                            Map<String, Object> newPost = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                            newPost.put("title", "Calculus");
                            newPost.put("teacher", "Mishal");
newPost.put("maxMarks", 100);
newPost.put("status", "cleared");
                            newPostRef.setValue(newPost);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you using instead of the names of the courses, the unique ids that are generated by the `push()` method. This means that the your database structure might look like this:

```
"user1": {
    "courses": {
        "-Kdfqjidfiqifnqifn": {
            "courseName": "science",
            "maxMarks": 100,
            "teacher": "Andrew",
            "title": "Amazing Science",
            "status": "cleared"

        },
        "-Kdfqjidfwefwty34d": {
            "courseName": "maths",
            "maxMarks": 100,
            "teacher": "Simon",
            "title": "Elementary Mathematics",
            "status": "cleared"
        },
        "-Kdfqjidfwer3t4yhdg": {
            "courseName": "history",
            "maxMarks": 80,
            "teacher": "Sarah",
            "title": "History",
            "status": "cleared"
        }
    }

}
```

You'll need to use this method directly on your reference like this:

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User").child(userId).child("courses");
DatabaseReference keyReference = databaseReference.push();
keyReference.setValue(yourMap)
```

In which `userId` is the `id` of the user.

In this way, you won't update the existing data, you'll add new one.

Hope it helps.

Comment: this is adding a course node in my main User node. i want to add inside User/user1/course/

Comment: that is the problem i am facing. By doing this (FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User").child(userId).child("courses");) it is overwriting the whole course node

Comment: Changing that name with an unique id will end up adding new data in stead of overwriting it.

Comment: i am still facing with the same issue. anybody please help

Comment: Alex, i am doing this     DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("user1").child("courses");
  DatabaseReference keyReference = databaseReference.push();
                            databaseReference.setValue(myMap);
                        }

Comment: Try to use in stead of `setValue()` method `updateChildren(myMap)` method. Works?

Comment: even push() gives a unique key to each child. It is deleting the old childs of courses and add a new child

Comment: plz help me guys.

Comment: `push()` method never deletes a child, it generates a unique id as explained above.

Comment: One thing I was doing is getting the ID and then using the .getKey() string property to create my own HashMap and then using .setValue() on the ref to save the object. Big mistake, you have to use .setValue() on the key that you just pushed.